# .htaccess rewrite rule not sending data

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following rule -

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

while trying to get the $_GET['url'] it gives me nothing, I enabled mod_rewrite but still.
For example if i enter this url localhost//index/main $url is empty although it should be "index/main"

ubuntu LTS 12.04
apache2

Comment: Do a `print_r($_SERVER);` and look for any key containing value `url=index/main`. Look for `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]`..

Comment: There is nothing like you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line on top of your .htaccess file:

> Options -MultiViews